# JavaScript Error in BIRT

Tags: java, javascript, eclipse, birt

I have been assigned to clean up a project for a client that uses BIRT reporting. I have fixed most of the issues but I still have one report that is not working and is returning an error. The error is:

```
Row (id = 1467): 
+ There are errors evaluating script "var fileName = row["Attached_File"];
params["HyperlinkParameter"].value = ImageDecoder.decodeDocs(row["Ecrash_Attach"],fileName);":
Wrapped java.lang.NullPointerException (/report/body/table[@id="61"]/detail/row[@id="70"]/cell[@id="71"]/grid[@id="1460"]/row[@id="1462"]/cell[@id="1463"]/table[@id="1464"]/detail/row[@id="1467"]/method[@name="onCreate"]#2)
```

I can post the full stack trace if someone wants it but for now I will omit it since it is very long.

Here is the source of the decodeDocs method:

```
public static String decodeDocs(byte[] source, String fileName) {
        String randName = "";
        byte[] docSource = null;
        if ( Base64.isArrayByteBase64(source) ){
            docSource = Base64.decodeBase64(source);
        }
        documentZipPath = writeByteStreamToFile(source);
        randName = writeByteStreamToFile(docSource, fileName);
        return randName;
    }
```

I am pretty well lost on this one. The error looks to be telling me there is an error on line two of the script which is:

```
var fileName = row["Attached_File"];
params["HyperlinkParameter"].value = ImageDecoder.decodeDocs(row["Ecrash_Attach"],fileName);
```

This is written in the OnCreate method of the report. Any help, even clues would be greatly appreciated. If you would like to see the report just ask and I will post the xml for it.

Comment: Please do NOT edit this post. This IS a JavaScript issue in BIRT, see the keyword var right there? you cant do that in Java

Comment: Are you trying to modify an existing report, or are you creating a new report from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

A common mistake I make in BIRT is to access the value of a null report parameter.
In your case, could `params["HyperlinkParameter"]` be null?